# Is it proven that all "solar" neutrinos are coming from the Sun direction?

Tags: experimental-physics, sun, neutrinos

In "Observation of 8B solar neutrinos in the Kamiokande-II detector" (Phys.Rev.Lett., 63, 16(1989), http://prl.aps.org/pdf/PRL/v63/i1/p16_1) the Figure 2 shows that only small percentage of registered neutrinos came from the Sun direction. The rest of registered events have random direction. Can it potentially mean that majority of the registered neutrinos came not from the Sun? If not how this background noise can be explained?

Answer (score 4):

That paper describes data from an early version of Kamiokande detector. Later versions can even take a picture of the Sun just using neutrinos: http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/ap980605.html.

The paper discusses various sources of background neutrinos. Whether it's worth going into the sources in detail is debatable since later versions of Kamiokande did so much better.

Comment: Banging through a thorough analysis of all the backgrounds is part of validating the detector and assuring the participants of earlier experiments that you have read their papers and dealt with the things that held them up for years. Hopefully you dealt with those things during the *design* phase, but you need to show that you *have* dealt with them one way or another. One of my papers has references only from my collaborators and from people saying *"we didn't need to do all the work that dmckee did because we planned around the issue..."*. Well, goody for them.